# How configure SLF4J underlying configuration file location

Tags: java, slf4j

Is it possible to tell SLF4J that my logging configuration file is on the path X and no matter what logging implementation I choose the underlying implementation should pick up that file on the path X?

Comment: SLF4J will pick up configuration file from root application classpath automatically.

Comment: Yes. I googled and found that logback conf file location can be set like this `System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "/path/to/config.xml")`. I wonder if there is a similar way to set file location in the code despite underlying logging implementation

Comment: Why would you want to do that and not use automatic discovery?